# PTIJ: What's wrong with my hamantashen?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I went to the store on Friday, two days before Purim, to buy ingredients for hamantashen.  The problem was, there were too many flavors of filling: strawberry, blueberry, apricot, and many more.  I wasn't sure which one to buy.

Then I noticed that there was a can of [mon filling](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/57/Q1/).  I know that there are a lot of special halachot related to mon, for instance that you can't leave it overnight unless that night is Shabbos.  But the can had a hechsher and it was on sale in a Jewish store, so I knew all those halachot were followed and it would be ok to serve on Purim night, Motzaei Shabbos.

I thought, "Great!  Now I can just buy that, and the hamantashen will taste like whatever I want!"  (As long as it's not cucumber, melon, leek, onion, or garlic, but who ever heard of hamantashen in those flavors anyway.)  (Rashi Bamidbar 11:5)

But it didn't work!  I had in mind that the hamantashen should taste like several different flavors, but their taste always stayed the same.  I didn't like the taste much, but I had to eat them all before morning anyway to avoid the issur of leaving mon until the morning.

What did I do wrong?  Why didn't they taste like whatever I wanted?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

Many years ago I heard that the *mon* only changed flavors for *tzaddikim*, not for everyone, and for normal people it was "like a taste of wafer with honey." In this generation, there are very few real *tzaddikim* and I guess you don't like the taste of wafers with honey too much :(

Comment: +1 thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't taste like that either...

Answer (score 1):

I feel you misunderstood. The filling is not "mon". The filling is "moon". This is why we eat it on the 14th and 15th of the month, so we are full of moon. By connecting it to mon (the Rastafarian treat) you miss the three corners of the holiday.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you're still not seeing how simple the answer is.

Near the beginning of the story about the mahn, the Torah explains exactly why it was called "mahn". It says that people saw this stuff lying on the ground, and said to each other "It's mahn", because they didn't know what it was.

If you have no clue as to what something is, how would you know what it's supposed to taste like? Huh? Have you thought of that???

So, what's happening, is that you're eating this mahn, and you're trying to compare something you know nothing about to taste like something that you DO know something about. Not only that, you're even EXPECTING it to taste like the thing you know something about. That's completely illogical! Not only don't you know what you're eating, you don't even understand what you're doing to yourself!

My advice - learn from your illogical mistake, and don't try this foolishness, again. Stick with things you know something about.